# C# problem for getting how much kg I should gain

Tags: c#

I have a computer of MMI (body mass index), according to the formula weight (kg) / Pow(height (m), 2). I tried to go further and write a code that recommends how many kg to lose weight or to gain weight depending on the optimal bmi.

For weight loss works well, the problem is fattening, does not reach the same optimal bmi.

Example.
If I have 100kg and 1.84m then you have to get to 29.5 you have to get to 24 pm to somewhere 87kg. So far so good
But if I have 30kg and 1.84 then you have to get to 8.8 you have to get to 24 and here's the problem that the formula recommends 64kg, which for 1.84, 64 kg is under the optimal bmi.

```
using System;

namespace BMI_Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // define variables
            double weight;
            double height;
            double optimalBmiMin = 18.5;
            double optimalBmiMax = 24;
            double bmiPointKg = 2.3;

            /*
            Console.WriteLine("BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("developer: dannybest");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.Clear();
            */

            Console.WriteLine("Write your weight in kg:");
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Write your height in m:");
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();

            // bmi formula rounded to two decimals
            double bmi = weight / Math.Pow(height, 2);

            // calculates the difference in kg;
            double weightDiffLose = (bmi - optimalBmiMax) * bmiPointKg;
            double weightDiffGain = (optimalBmiMax - bmi) * bmiPointKg;

            // calculates the recomanded kg for your height based on bmi score;
            double recLoseKg = weight - weightDiffLose;
            double recGainKg = weight + weightDiffGain;

            // if is under optimal BMI score, calculate how much you should gain
            if (bmi < optimalBmiMin)
            {
                if (bmi < 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Very serious underweight");

                }
                else if (bmi > 15.0 && bmi < 16.0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Severely underweight");
                }
                else if (bmi > 16.0 && bmi < 18.5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Underweight");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You should gain: " + weightDiffGain + " kg");
                Console.WriteLine("Recomanded kg for your height: " + recGainKg + " kg / " + height + " m");
            }
            // else if above optimal BMI score, calculate how much you should lose
            else if (bmi > optimalBmiMax)
            {
                if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI score is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health status: Overweight");
                }
                else if (bmi > 30 && bmi < 35)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class I (moderately obese)");
                }
                else if (bmi > 35 && bmi < 40)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class II (strictly obese)");
                }
                else if (bmi > 40)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class III (very seriously obese)");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You should lose: " + weightDiffLose + " kg");
                Console.WriteLine("Recomanded kg for your height: " + recLoseKg + " kg / " + height + " m");
            }
            // else normal BMI score
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your BMI score is: " + bmi);
                Console.WriteLine("Health status: Normal (healthy weight)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the code has problem. if the person is 1.84m then suppose the weight of the individual is 64 as per the recommended, bmi = 64/(1.84*1.84) = 18.9 which is healthy

Comment: Rewrite the BMI formula to `targetWeight = targetBmi * (height ^ 2)` and use that to calculate required gain (to minBmi) or loss (to maxBmi)

Comment: Thanks guys I just researched a little and I found I need a divine formula.

Answer (score 1):

divine formula

```
            // Ideal Body Weight
            double heightInch = height / 0.0254;
            double ibwKg = 50 + 2.3 * (heightInch - 60);

            // calculates the diff
            double diffKg = ibwKg - weight;
```

```
using System;

namespace BMI_Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // define variables
            double weight;
            double height;

            /*
            Console.WriteLine("BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("developer: dannybest");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.Clear();
            */

            Console.WriteLine("Write your weight in kg:");
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Write your height in m:");
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();

            // bmi formula
            double bmi = weight / Math.Pow(height, 2);

            // Ideal Body Weight
            double heightInch = height / 0.0254;
            double ibwKg = 50 + 2.3 * (heightInch - 60);

            // calculates the diff
            double diffKg = ibwKg - weight;

            // if is under optimal BMI score, calculate how much you should gain
            if (bmi < 18.5)
            {
                if (bmi < 15)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Very serious underweight");

                }
                else if (bmi > 15.0 && bmi < 16.0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Severely underweight");
                }
                else if (bmi > 16.0 && bmi < 18.5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Underweight");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You should gain: " + diffKg + " kg");
                Console.WriteLine("Recomanded kg for your height: " + ibwKg + " kg / " + height + " m");
            }
            // else if above optimal BMI score, calculate how much you should lose
            else if (bmi > 25)
            {
                if (bmi > 25 && bmi < 30)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI score is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health status: Overweight");
                }
                else if (bmi > 30 && bmi < 35)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class I (moderately obese)");
                }
                else if (bmi > 35 && bmi < 40)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class II (strictly obese)");
                }
                else if (bmi > 40)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + bmi);
                    Console.WriteLine("Health: Obese Class III (very seriously obese)");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You should lose: " + diffKg + " kg");
                Console.WriteLine("Recomanded kg for your height: " + ibwKg + " kg / " + height + " m");
            }
            // else normal BMI score
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your BMI score is: " + bmi);
                Console.WriteLine("Health status: Normal (healthy weight)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```